# PowerShell v5.1: problem with replacing text in a file using regex patterns

Tags: regex, powershell-5.1

I tried to follow answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144355/how-can-i-replace-every-occurrence-of-a-string-in-a-file-with-powershell) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250258/replace-the-content-of-a-textfile-with-a-regex-in-powershell).

In a "`test1.txt`" file I have these contents:

```
20220421
20220422
20220423
20220424:
222
```

I want to replace the contents so that they would look like this in the output file "`test2.txt`":

```
20220421:
20220422:
20220423:
20220424:
222
```

I attempted to achieve this with the following code:

```
(Get-Content '.\test1.txt').replace('^\d{8}$', '^\d{8}:$') | Out-File '.\test2.txt'
```

However, instead of the expected results, I got the following content in "`test2.txt`":

```
20220421
20220422
20220423
20220424:
222
```

Can someone explain why I'm not achieving the expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the regex supporting `-replace` operator and you are usinv a regex in the replacement instead of the correct replacement pattern.

You can use

```
(Get-Content '.\test1.txt') -replace '^(\d{8}):?\r?$', '$1:') | Out-File '.\test2.txt'
```

The `^(\d{8}):?\r?$` regex matches eight digits capturing them into Group 1, and then an optional colon, an optional CR and then asserts the end of string position.

The replacement is Group 1 value (`$1`) plus the colon char.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is treating $ and ^ as the beginning and end of the whole contents, not individual lines.

This is not quite what you want - I can't get the line break in the replacement string.

@"
20220421
20220422
20220423
20220424:
222
"@ -replace "(\d{8})\n",'$1:'

line breaks not working